# Comparing variable values and key names with full stops/periods in Twig

Tags: php, json, cakephp, twig

My CakePHP view element for outputting a script tag has a variable called `scriptsGroup` with a value of, for example, `main` passed to it.

Twig:

```
{{ dump(scriptsGroup) }}
```

Output:

```
string(4) "main"
```

I also have the following view array called `busters`.

Twig:

```
{{ dump(busters) }}
```

Output:

```
object(stdClass)#134 (2) {
  ["public/js/build/main.js"]=>
  string(8) "7e9a1c32"
  ["public/css/main.css"]=>
  string(8) "d41d8cd9"
}
```

In Twig, how can I check that the script referred to by the `scriptsGroup` variable (in this case, `main`) is in the `busters` array, and, if it is, output a script tag with the relevant hash in the filename.

Example of desired output:

```
<script src="/js/build/main_rev-7e9a1c32.js"></script>
```

I don't know how to deal with the array keys having full stops/periods and how to match the variable with the key of the array. I've tried the `#{}` interpolation syntax but am failing.

**Update:** I've tried using `~`:

```
{% if busters['public/js/build/' ~ scriptsGroup ~ '.js'] %}
```

gives `Impossible to access a key "public/js/build/main.js" on an object of class "stdClass" that does not implement ArrayAccess interface`.

**Update 2:** I realised I wasn't properly using PHP's `json_decode` function - it's now converting to an associative array so my new `if` condition is working. I just need to output the script tag now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{% if busters['public/js/build/' ~ scriptsGroup ~ '.js'] %}
    <script src="/js/build/{{ scriptsGroup }}_rev-{{ busters['public/js/build/' ~ scriptsGroup ~ '.js'] }}.js"></script>
{% endif %}
```

It uses [the `[]` and `~` operators](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#other-operators).